# Redux - Updating deeply nested store props using spread operator

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am building a relatively large web app using react+redux and dealing with my store is getting really confusing.

I came up with a problem in updating nested properties in store and found [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) section of redux docs which indicates I should do something like this:

```
function updateVeryNestedField(state, action) {
    return {
        ....state,
        first : {
            ...state.first,
            second : {
                ...state.first.second,
                [action.someId] : {
                    ...state.first.second[action.someId],
                    fourth : action.someValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I've done so, and as a result some parts of my reducers are looking like this:

```
.
.
.
case "CHANGE_RANGED_INPUT": {
        return {
          ...state,
          searchPanel: {
            ...state.searchPanel,
            [action.payload.category]: {
              ...state.searchPanel[action.payload.category],
              rangedInputs: {
                ...state.searchPanel[action.payload.category].rangedInputs,
                [action.payload.type]: {
                  ...state.searchPanel[action.payload.category].rangedInputs[action.payload.type],
                  [action.payload.key]: {
                    ...state.searchPanel[action.payload.category].rangedInputs[action.payload.type][action.payload.key],
                    value: action.payload.value
                  }
                }
              },
            }
          },
        }
      }
.
.
.
```

I guess you agree that my code is getting more confusing than it should be. My question is not about the performance of the way recommended by redux docs (eventhough it feels like a lot of work for an action which in my case is dispatched almost every second) and I assume it is the best way.

My question is about readability of my code. Is there an approach which can make my reducer cleaner?

Actually I am using [react-redux-form](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form) for some of my giant forms, not because I need all the features this library is providing, but to use just one feature of it. this library lets me create a huge form model with lots of nested stuff and all I have to do is add its model route to the input to get its predefined onChange events working and the related values updating.

Is this library doing so with spread operator under its hood?

Is there any other way like adding some index to some input and be able to update the related value in the store with that index when input value is changed?

Comment: It sounds like the shape of your data is simply too nested to conveniently manipulate. Have a read of "Normalizing state shape" in the redux docs and see if you can re-organise your state into a more convenient shape. http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Comment: Like @DavidL.Walsh said, you might want to consider normalizing your state shape. Also, [ImmutableJS](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) is said to help deal with nested structures like this though I haven't used it, myself. I still think you should normalize your state first before trying out that library.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I surely will reconsider my store shape. I also noticed these lines: "Obviously, each layer of nesting makes this harder to read, and gives more chances to make mistakes. This is one of several reasons why you are encouraged to keep your state flattened, and compose reducers as much as possible." I guess I have to split some of my reducers into multiple reducers.

Comment: @DonovanM wow man. this ImmutableJs is awesome. fits perfect for what I need. thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. Hope it works out for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found dozens of utilities for this in redux docs!
[Immutable Update Utilities](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md#immutable-update-utilities)

and I think [dot-prop-immutable](https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable) is pretty simple and straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that list. I honestly haven't looked at it since last year and it sure has grown haha

Comment: dot-prop-immutable for the win :)

Comment: Aaaaaand that is why I keep updating that list with the libraries I've found :)  Glad it helps!